# Sticky Toolbar for Tinymce 5.0 Version

Tags: tinymce, sticky, tinymce-5

Since the version changed, i am using 5.0.9 Tinymce Editor. Sticky toolbar save lots of time while working on large content.

Tried integrating Sticky Toolbar in Editor but seem it dosent work.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: 'a11ychecker advcode casechange formatpainter linkchecker autolink lists checklist media mediaembed pageembed permanentpen powerpaste table advtable tinymcespellchecker autoresize',
    toolbar: 'a11ycheck addcomment showcomments casechange checklist code formatpainter pageembed permanentpen table', 
    toolbar_sticky: true,
    toolbar_sticky_offset: 80
});
```

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/DPhaab

Answer (score 1):

The sticky toolbar feature was only added in [TinyMCE 5.1](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/release-notes/release-notes51/#stickytoolbar) and the toolbar offset was added in [TinyMCE 5.9](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/release-notes/release-notes59/#newtoolbar_sticky_offsetoptionforcustomizingstickytoolbars). As such, to use these features you'll need to upgrade your TinyMCE version to at least TinyMCE 5.9.0. You'll see in https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/DPhaab/1, which I've updated to use 5.10.0, that the sticky toolbar feature works.

It's also worth noting that TinyMCE 5.0 is no longer supported by Tiny as of August 5, 2020: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/enterprise/system-requirements/#supportedtinymceversions